# CodeIgniter Captcha Image name

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

CodeIgniter Captcha `create_captcha($val)` creates captcha and returns the image within the `img` tag but is it possible to get only the image name?

**Example**

CI Captcha returns `<img src='abc.jpg'>`

What I require `abc.jpg` only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the docs, the function returns an array, with data that includes the image name: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html

Comment: It returns the image as an image tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the imagename and set it as you want.

> CodeIgniter/system/helpers/captcha_helper.php line 231

```
// change here. you can set your desired name here.
$img_name = $your_name.'.jpg';
```

You can modify it directly (probably not a good idea as updates may overwrite). Or you could create your own helper by copying the original, modifying and putting it in application/helpers.

So, copy `captcha_helper.php` into application/helpers, make the changes on line  231, save, and you should be good.

Comment: Basically what I wanted was to place the captcha image with AJAX (json) but since CI returns image tag it was able to catch it.
Adding empty quotes before and after the CI captcha variable solved it.

Answer (score 0):

according to the manual

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html?highlight=captcha#create_captcha

this function allways return the img tag, the only thing i think you can do is parse it using regular expressions ...

```
preg_match("/\w+='(\w+.\w+)'/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

References

http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php

http://www.phpliveregex.com/